# custom url in php using htaccess (url rewriting)

Tags: .htaccess

i am new in url rewriting in php htaccess. currently my url as like 
 http://localhost/htaccess/Movie/my-parameter-value

but i want to http://localhost/htaccess/my-parameter-value
 i want remove Movie (movies is from action source  name ex "movie.php"); 
**Thanks In Advance**

here is my code :

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On     
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)(?:\+|%20|\s)+(.+?)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [L,NE,R=302]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php?name=123 to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?name=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R,L]     


# To internally forward /dir/foo/12 to /dir/foo.php?name=12
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)?$ $1.php?name=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: my htaccess located in root directory. because in domianame.com/parameter-value helps to seo boosting for that i have to remove Movie

Comment: sorry htaccess is my application folder name

Comment: ya thats the original url

Comment: ya thats the original url  :"http://localhost/htaccess/Movie.php?name=my parameter value"       and i have converted space in dash(-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On     
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)(?:\+|%20|\s)+(.+?)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [L,NE,R=302]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php?name=123 to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s(.*)/Movie\.php\?name=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R,L]     

# /htaccess/Movie.php?name=movie-name => /htaccess/movie-name
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?name=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R,L]     

# To internally forward /dir/foo/12 to /dir/foo.php?name=12
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?name=$2 [L,QSA]

# handle /htaccess/movie-name internally
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ Movie.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: thank's a lot!  anubhava you solved my problem i am struggling from months for that thanks.

Comment: can i send two parameter name and id but in url show only name not id and in Movie.php can i access that id echo $_GET['id'];  ?

Comment: No that won't be possible. Once `id` parameter is removed from URL you cannot retrieve in `php` file. Having `id` is a good idea see this question's URL in SO